# Problem after deleting a system partition on another HD

Tags: debian, filesystems

While installing Debian Wheezy, I decided to use my another HD as `/home/igor/Documents/`, and the system installed correctlly nothing wrong happened, but later I decided to delete that partition so I did it, so now everytime I boot system, while it's loading, an error  an error stop the loading process and then ask me to enter with the "maintainer password" (root) or to press Ctrl + D to continue the loading process. The error says that there is a problem with the "file system". And a log appears on `/var/log/fsck/checkfs` and when you open it with `nano /var/log/fsck/checkfs` this message is inside:

```
Log of fsck -C -R -A -a
Sun Sep  9 16:37:18 2012

fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=0f0123f4-2870-42e0-ad18-de837a6d2aed'
fsck died with exit status 8

Sun Sep  9 16:37:18 2012
----------------
```

How can Ifix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve
>   'UUID=0f0123f4-2870-42e0-ad18-de837a6d2aed'

That is the partition you have deleted. Most likely /etc/fstab still references that partition UUID so you should adjust /etc/fstab according to your new setup.